# What are Trubies?

Tags: short-stories, nalo-hopkinson, bordertown-series

Nalo Hopkinson's short story "Ours is the Prettiest" (published in the collection Falling in Love with Hominids, 2015) mentions Trubies several times, for example:

Page 190:

> I swung aside the skeletal bustle that was the skirt of my gown just in time to get it out from underfoot of a staggerline of Trubies, everyone of them dressed to pussfoot in gleaming white canvas bell-bottoms, sailor shirts and beanies. (page 190)

Page 190 (emphasis mine):

> I shook my head at the silver flask one of them slid out of a back pocket to offer me. She was only being friendly, but they had a way of forgetting that some of the things they drank for pleasure **could cause humans serious pain**. (page 190, emphasis mine)

Page 206 (about a Trubie that is later referred to as a snake charmer):

> The Trubie was ancient as the hills and thrice as wrinkled. He had a boa constrictor draped over his arms. Age had blanched the two braids hanging down his back from silver to pure white. They were each nearly as thick around as the snake, and their tips tickled his dusty ankles.

Page 209:

> *Through the windows of the bus, we saw Beti stand and take the hand of a pretty Trubie girl, tall and slim with big cat eyes and a complicated fall of silvery hair.* (...) 
>   Betti told me that Lizzie [the "Trubie girl" from the bus] wasn't even a Trubie. Just one of the rare humans who kinda looked like one.

In 2011 the story was also published in *Welcome to Bordertown*, an anthology with stories by more than twenty authors. The anthology is part of [Bordertown (or Borderland) series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Borderland_Series), which is an example of a [shared-world](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_universe) series: multiple authors can use each other's characters (as long as they don't kill them).

So my question is whether the Trubies are Nalo Hopkinson's invention or were invented by one of the other authors who have contributed to the series.

Comment: true blood fanatics ;)